# Alternative ways to show type info when editing TypeScript in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When editing Typescript in VSCode, is there an option to show the type of identifiers when you click them (instead of having to hover over them)? And can the type info be shown in a panel at the bottom or side?

I find hovering to see types kind of finicky; a little move of the pointer and the type info could disappear, or sometimes the type information is too much to comfortably view in the small tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

This extension might help by annotating the types:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinJohns.inline-types

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to show them when clicking, but if you have your caret/text cursor on a symbol that you want to find the type of, you can press ctrl-space and it will show you suggestions (including type information).

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice vscode extension that helps with that, not by click but with comments.

**[Twoslash Query Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-twoslash-queries)** by [Orta](https://www.youtube.com/user/ortatherox)

You add these comments to see variables types:

- `// =>` at the end of the line shows the type of its leftmost variable.
- `// ^?` under the line shows the type of the variable above the caret.

and the comments get updated automatically.

[image]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-twoslash-queries